# Upgrade to Rails 5.1, gem `query_reviewer` and deprecated method `alias_method_chain`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Rails community!

I'm having an issue about upgrading on Rails project from Rails 4.2 to Rails 5.2, issue related to the step from Rails 5.0 to 5.1

```
/gems/query_reviewer-0.2.2/lib/query_reviewer/mysql_adapter_extensions.rb:4:in `included': undefined method `alias_method_chain' for ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter:Class (NoMethodError)
```

I've  read a lot of related questions here, and I understood that method `alias_method_chains` is deprecated with Rails 5.1...

However, here, issue comes from a gem, especially gem `query_reviewer` ([github](https://github.com/nesquena/query_reviewer), [rubygems](https://rubygems.org/gems/query_reviewer)):
Last version of this gem is 0.2.2 (septembre 16, 2013) and includes the deprecated method:

```
module QueryReviewer
  module MysqlAdapterExtensions
    def self.included(base)
      base.alias_method_chain :select, :review
      base.alias_method_chain :update, :review
      base.alias_method_chain :insert, :review
      base.alias_method_chain :delete, :review
    end
```

Obviously, this gem is not available with Rails 5.1, and obvious but painful option would be to look for an other gem... But, maybe, someone had the same issue and found a better way to answer to this 1st question as StackOverflow user ;) ?

Thanks by advance

Comment: Fork, rewrite it and point gem to your new repo `gem 'query_reviewer ', :git => 'git://github.com/username/repo.git'`:)

Comment: This is unfortunately the only solution if you want to use Rails 5.x with a gem not designed for it - and it's easier than it sounds!

Comment: Especially in this case since it should be as simple as using `Module#prepend` [This Article might help](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/rails-5-module-number-prepend-and-the-end-of-alias-method-chain/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In rails 5+ alias_method_chain has removed, so in place of this we can use alias_method like below

```
  base.alias_method :select_without_review, :select
  base.alias_method :select, :select_with_review
  base.alias_method :update_without_review, :update
  base.alias_method :update, :update_with_review
  base.alias_method :insert_without_review, :insert
  base.alias_method :insert, :insert_with_review
  base.alias_method :delete_without_review, :delete
  base.alias_method :delete, :delete_with_review
```